# Can you do modulos with irrational numbers?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, irrational-numbers

The other day, I was tutoring a fellow student on modulos, and we came across the topic of modular fractions. As far as I have learned, there are essentially two ways to do modulos with fractions, simply use them as remainders, or actually use some modulo manipulation. As an example I gave him, if you were to do $$9.5 \equiv ? \mod{5}$$ we could just write the answer as $4.5$, that would be the "easy" solution, but instead you could solve the equation $$\frac{19}{2}\equiv \mod{5}$$ $$4\equiv2n \mod{5}$$ $$n\equiv2 \mod{5}$$, so $9.5$ would in fact be equivalent to 2 modulo 5. Now, he asked a very intriguing question, what would $\pi$ be, say, modulo 2? I had no answer. My guess would be to take successively better approximations, but would that converge to one number? Does saying "what is $\pi$ mod 2" even make sense? Or is there no special answer and it's just 1.1415926...

Comment: It makes sense to define $\equiv$ as $x \equiv y \mod z$ if $x-y$ is divisible by $z$. In this sense $19/2$ is not equivalent to $2$ mod $5$. It *is* true that $2(19/2) \equiv 4 \mod 5$, but because you added in fractions, you can't divide inside modulo relations anymore (which you could before because $5$ is prime).

Comment: It's important to remember that 3 mod 2 is not the integer 1, but rather the equivalence class of which both 1 and 3 are members. A separate issue is that you're confusing $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ with $\mathbb{R}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Ian, thank you for your response, but I'm sure that I have learned that 19/2 is equivalent to 2 in modulo 5 somewhere, I don't know if that is like a special branch of mathematics or something, but my class had a whole week on dealing with special cases of mod.

Comment: @RghtHndSd I haven't learned as far as equivalence classes yet, I'm afraid, if it would be possible to keep this in layman terms that would be best.

Comment: Just to compare: in Pari/GP they have it implemented this way: `9.5 % 5  --->  4.50000000000` , then  `(19/2) % 5 --->  2` and with real modulus `9.5 % 5.0 --> 4.50000000000` and `(19/2) % 5.0 -->  4.50000000000`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can interpret modular arithmetic in both of the ways you illustrate, but one of them is a lot more common than the other in mathematics.

The one that's universally understood is the one in which
$$
\frac{19}{2} \equiv 2 \pmod{5}.
$$
The reason is that 
$$
3 \times 2 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}
$$
so $3$ is the multiplicative inverse of $2$ and

$$
\frac{19}{2} \equiv 19 \times 3 \equiv 2 \pmod{5}.
$$
In that context you would never write $19/2$ as the decimal $9.5$.

Moveover, in that context expressions like $\pi \pmod{5}$ make no sense at all and some that seem to are impossible. For example, $19/2$ makes no sense modulo $6$ since $2$ does not have a multiplicative inverse modulo $6$.

The other way modular arithmetic is sometimes construed (in computer languages rather than pure mathematics) is as the remainder when you subtract the largest possible multiple of the modulus. I don't want to use $\equiv$ to write that because it bothers my mathematical sensitivity so I will use $\%$ as do some programming languages. Then
$$
19.5 \ \% \ 5 = 4.5
$$
and, as you say, 
$$
\pi \ \% \ 2 = \pi - 2 = 1.14159\ldots
$$.

Comment: Okay, I get that the first definition wouldn't work with irrationals, thank you.

Comment: @Gabe Also beware that such notation can be ambiguous, e.g. if $\,x\equiv 4/2 \pmod {\!10}\,$ then $\,x\equiv 2\pmod{\!10}\,$ if the slash denotes division in $\,\Bbb Z,\,$ but $\,x\equiv 2\pmod{\!5}\,$ if the division is in $\,\Bbb Z/5,\,$ since $$\ 2x\equiv 4\!\!\pmod{\!10}\iff 2x = 4\! +\!10n\iff x = 2\! +\! 5n\iff x\equiv 2\!\!\pmod{\! 5}\ $$

Comment: As such, usually we restrict to denominators *coprime* to the modulus, where $\,a/b \equiv ab^{-1}\,$ *uniquely exists*, and familiar fraction arithmetic is valid for all such modular fractions.

Comment: Well, I do know that division doesn't work in modular arithmetic, say 3x=9 mod 6, x could be 1, 3, or 5 but dividing by 3 gives you only x = 3.

Comment: Upps, didn't see this answer when I wrote my small comment showing the Pari/GP - usance. Please see that comment associated to then OP's question...

Comment: Is it sensible to say $2\pi \equiv 0 \pmod{\pi}$?

Comment: @ShubhavJain Yes, in one of the two interpretations of $\equiv$ in the answer.