# Value of $\pi$ modulo a prime

Tags: field-theory, modular-arithmetic, pi

Given a radius of a circle ***r*** and a prime ***p***, you need to tell, what would be the **area** $A$ of this circle modulo ***p*** (the statement of the problem also gives an example: $r = 1, p = 7, A = 3$.

The solution of this problem uses the regular formula for the circle area:
$$A = \pi r^{2}$$
However it uses the polynomial ring ${\mathbb{Z}}_{p}[X]$ to find an $a \equiv \pi\pmod p$. First it find an inverse of the polynomial $f(x) = x^{2}+1$: $$g(x)\equiv\frac{1}{x^{2}+1}\pmod p,$$ using the Fast Fourier Transform. Then it computes the integral of $g(x)$, since
$$\int \frac{1}{x^2+1}dx=\arctan(x)$$
The final step is to calculate $a\equiv\pi\equiv4\arctan(1)\equiv4G(1)\pmod p$

I know how the Fourier Transform works. I also know that you normally would use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm to compute the inverse of a polynomial modulo another polynomial. So I'm just confused, how would you compute an inverse of a polynomial modulo a prime integer? The solution also suggests that $\deg(g(x))=p-2$.

Comment: Unless you make a second, luckier attempt at telling us what you're talking about, I'm afraid there won't be very many useful answers.

Comment: It isn't at all clear what you mean.  There isn't a polynomial $g(x)$ such that $g(x)\times (x^2+1)\equiv 1 $ as a polynomial $\pmod p$ if that's what you were asking.

Comment: You might need to add a copy of whatever text you have read.

Comment: In $\mod3$, $(x^2+1)^2$ is always $1$, so you might call $x^2+1$ its own inverse.  If $p=4k-1$, then $x^2+1$ is coprime to $x^p-x$, and there must be polynomials with $a(x)(x^2+1)+b(x)(x^p-x)=1$

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to have been answered.
Refer: [Can you do modulos with irrational numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3332418/can-you-do-modulos-with-irrational-numbers)

Basically,
$$a\equiv\pi\equiv4\arctan(1)\equiv4G(1)\pmod p$$

in your computations could in fact be construed to mean,

$$a \% p = \pi \% p = 4\arctan(1)\%p = 4G(1)\%p$$

As is stated, it becomes senseless otherwise, since we can't find the multiplicative inverse of $\pi\pmod p$ or do this for any transcendental or irrational number.